# java: memoizing construction through hash function

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

I have an X object whose constructor takes in 4 integers fields. To calculate it's hash function, I simple throw them in an array and use Arrays.hashCode.

Currently the constructor is private and I have a static creator method. I'd like to memoize construction so that whenever the creator method is called with 4 integer parameters that have been called before, I can return the same object as last time. [Ideally without having to create another X object to compare with.]

Originally I tried a hashSet but that required me to create a new X to check if my hashSet.contains the equal object... nevermind the fact that I can't 'get' out of a hashSet.

My next idea is to use a HashTable which maps:
the hashCode of the int array of the 4 fields --> object. I'm not sure why, but that doesn't feel right. It feels like I'm doing too much work, isn't the point of a hashCode to be a sort of mapping to a bunch of objects which calculate to the same hashCode?

I appreciate your advice.

Comment: using a HashTable seems okay (I believe you can skip the hashCode and just pass in the array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you plan to use the Hashtable but I think below would do your job:

```
    private static Hashtable<Integer, MyObject> objectInstances = 
             new Hashtable<Integer, MyObject>();


    public static MyObject instance(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4){
         int hashKey = Arrays.hashCode(new int[]{i1, i2,i3,i4});
         //get the object from hashtable
         MyObject myObject = objectInstances.get(hashKey);

         //if object was not already created, create now and put in the hashtable
         if(myObject == null){
           myObject = new MyObject(i1,i2,i3,i4);
           objectInstances.put(hashKey, myObject);
         }
        return myObject;
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking of doing. The way this works is using the Integer's hashCode (= hashCode of my Object) to determine what bucket the MyObject is in.

What I was suggesting was cutting out the middleman and using the MyObject's hashCode to determine what bucket it'd be in. Perhaps, what I'm suggesting is a hashList? Does Java have anything like this?

Comment: @user1850672 Don't think that such list exists.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of a hash code is generally to *narrow down* the location in which to look for a particular object. Or put another way, the idea is that your hash code makes it so that if two objects have the same hash code they are "very likely" to be the same object.

Now, how likely is "very likely" essentially depends on the width (number of bits) and quality of the hash code. In the case of Java, with 32 bit hash codes, this "very likely" still generally means "not near enough to 100% that you can do away with an actual comparison of the object data". So as well as implementing hashCode(), you need to implement equals() on an object that is used as the key to a Java Map (HashMap etc).

Or put another way: your implementation is essentially correct, even though it looks like you're doing a lot of work. The upshot is that if what you are looking for is a performance improvement, you may as well just create a new object each time. But if functionally you require that there never exists more than one object with a given set of values, then your implementation is essentially correct.

Things you could do in principle:

- if you had a large number of ints, then for the hashCode(), just form the hash code from a 'sample' of a couple of them -- the idea is to 'narrow down the choices' or make it 'fairly but not 100% likely' that equal hash code will mean equal object-- your equals() has to go through and check them anyway, so there's little point in cycling through all values in both hashCode() and equals();
- potentially, you can use a stronger hash code, so that you literally assume that equal hash codes mean equal objects. In effect, you cycle through all of the values once in the hash code function and don't have an equals function at all. In practice this means using at least a strong-ish 64 bit hash code. It's probably not worth it for the case you mention. But if you want to understand a little about how it would work, I would point you to a tutorial I wrote on the [advanced use of hash codes in Java](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/hash_codes_advanced_statistics.shtml).

Comment: I understand, and I do in fact have a proper equals method.

In my particular case, there only about 5000 valid combinations of those 4 integer parameters. So I believe that the hashCode function should be sufficient to narrow down which bucket I'm looking at. It seems unnecessary to have to map the hashCode -> object. 

On second glance, the hashCode of an Integer is often that Integers value. Am I just explicitly doing what I had hoped would happen implicitly?

Comment: If there are only 5000 combinations, then you are probably best ignoring Arrays.hashCode() and trying to work out, using what you know about your data, how to pack those values into (say) a 32 bit int that will always be unique for a given set of values. Or maybe post information about the possible range of the 4 values if you need help with this.

Comment: And if you can predict in advance all of the possible combinations and that number is samll, you can of course simply test by brute force to make sure that your hash code never produces collisions for any of the permitted combinations of values.

Answer (score 1):

If the 4 integers during construction mean the resulting object will be exactly the same, then use those as the key, not their hash.  Notice I'm not using your full Object as the key, just the 4 integer values.  The MyObjectSpecification below will be a tiny object.

```
public class MyObjectSpecification {
    private final int i1, i2, i3, i4;

    public MyObjectSpecification(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4) {
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
        this.i3 = i3;
        this.i4 = i4;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // ...
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class MyObject {
    private static final Map<MyObjectSpecification, MyObject> myObjects
            = new ConcurrentHashMap<MyObjectSpecification, MyObject>();

    private MyObject(MyObjectSpecification spec) {
        // ...
    }

    public static MyObject getMyObject(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4) {
        MyObjectSpecification spec = new MyObjectSpecification(i1, i2, i3, i4);

        if (myObjects.containsKey(spec)) {
            return myObjects.get(spec);
        }

        MyObject newObject = new MyObject(spec);
        myObjects.put(spec, newObject);
        return newObject;
    }
}
```